# two layouts using video view in fragment orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a application has two different layout in portrait and landscape.

Each layout contain two fragments. One fragment contains a video view which plays a video from the internet. When orientation is changed, the video restarts.

I want to play the video without restarting.

Here is my code:

```
**This is my main activity.**
------------------------    


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            VIdeoFragment vfr = null;
            ImageFragment ifr = null;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
            vfr = new VIdeoFragment();
            ifr = new ImageFragment();
           FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           ft1.add(R.id.upper_view, vfr, "Vfr");
           ft2.add(R.id.down_view, ifr, "IFR");

            ft1.commit();
            ft2.commit();
            }
            }

    **--------------------------------
    VIdeoFragment** 



public class VIdeoFragment extends Fragment {
            VideoView vv,oldVV;
            View view=null;
 public static String movieUri =  "http://www.prep-zone.com/androidVideo/College Admission from Prep Zone (HD).mp4";
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                Uri video = Uri.parse(movieUri); 
                vv.setVideoURI(video);
                vv.start();
                    }
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video, container, false);

                    vv = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                    return view; 
                }
            }
    ---------------------------------------------
    ImageFragment 



public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, container,false);  
                }
}
    -------------------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

            </LinearLayout>

    ------------------------------


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>
                -------------------------------------
                portrait main xml
                ----------------



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/upper_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/down_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

                ------------------------------------
                landscape xml
                ----------------


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/upper_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/down_view"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
--------------------------------------------------------


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

        ================================================
        please help.Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

In manifest for the MainActivity, put config change for orientation.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Then in code of Main Activity override configuration change if you need to handle orientation change.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

This will avoid activity restarts and there by avoids the video playing again.

Comment: I did this.But not success.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Replying for those, who are still coming to this post for the solution:-( for API level 13 and later)

In manifest.xml file for the MainActivity, add the following in  tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

android:configChanges -lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called,which we can override to do something specific.

The other way is saving Fragment's state.

In code(VideoFragment class as per the problem statement)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Code to fetch Fragment saved arguments
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

By default, the retainInstance property of a fragment is false.So, it is not retained, and it is destroyed and recreated on rotation along with the activity that hosts it. Calling
setRetainInstance(true) retains the fragment. When a fragment is retained, the fragment is not destroyed with the activity. Instead, it is preserved and passed along intact to the new activity.

When you retain a fragment, you can count on all of its instance variables to keep the same values. When you reach for them, they are simply there.

For detailed information, refer [Retaining Fragment during configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)